# How do you reference the current item from a DataTemplate?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, c++-winrt

I'm trying to use a [function in an `x:Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings) markup extension from a [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate), but cannot seem to name the argument to pass along.

The following is a rough outline of what's working already. It is based on a default-generated [Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/winui-project-templates-in-visual-studio#blank-app-packaged-winui-3-in-desktop) template (using `FmtDemo` as the project name) with a few changes:

*MainWindow.idl*

```
namespace FmtDemo
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
    {
        IVector<Item> Items { get; };
    }

    runtimeclass Item
    {
        String Text { get; };
    }
}
```

The `MainWindow` type has a single property `Items` that returns an `IVector` of `Item`s. The `Item` type provides a single property `Text` for testing. These are the corresponding source files (modulo `#include` directives).

*MainWindow.xaml.h*

```cpp
namespace winrt::FmtDemo::implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow>
    {
        MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

        winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<winrt::FmtDemo::Item> Items() {
            return single_threaded_observable_vector(std::vector { make<Item>() });
        }
    };
}
```

*Item.h*

```cpp
namespace winrt::FmtDemo::implementation
{
    struct Item : ItemT<Item>
    {
        hstring Text() { return hstring { L"Some text" }; }
    };
}
```

*App.xaml.h*

```cpp
namespace winrt::FmtDemo::implementation
{
    struct App : AppT<App>
    {
        App() { InitializeComponent(); }

        void OnLaunched(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::LaunchActivatedEventArgs const&)
        {
            window = make<MainWindow>();
            window.Activate();
        }

    private:
        winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window window{ nullptr };
    };
}
```

The corresponding XAML markup that describes the contents of `MainWindow` is similarly simple:

```xml
<Window x:Class="FmtDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:FmtDemo">

    <ListView x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Window>
```

The `MainWindow` holds a `ListView` control whose `ItemsSource` is bound to the `MainWindow.Items` property. The `DataTemplate` contains a `TextBlock` control with its `Text` property bound to `Item.Text`. All that works as expected.

What I'm trying to do now is moving the formatting code into a dedicated `Formatter` type, starting with the *MainWindow.idl* by adding the following:

```
namespace FmtDemo
{
    // ...

    static runtimeclass Formatter
    {
        static String FmtItem(Item item);
    }
}
```

and implementing it in *Formatter.h*

```cpp
namespace winrt::FmtDemo::implementation
{
    struct Formatter
    {
        static hstring FmtItem(winrt::FmtDemo::Item const& item)
        {
            return L"Formatted: " + item.Text();
        }
    };
}

namespace winrt::FmtDemo::factory_implementation
{
    struct Formatter : FormatterT<Formatter, implementation::Formatter> {};
}
```

The `Formatter` type is accessible from the XAML markup, but the issue I'm having is naming the `Item` reference from the `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="FmtDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FmtDemo">

    <ListView x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:Formatter.FmtItem( ??? )}" />
                <!--- What should                                 ^^^ this be? -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Window>
```

The `???` in the XAML above should reference the current `Item` (`DataContext`, I guess?) but I don't know how to name it.

What should the `???` be here (unless that's something that's not supported)?

Comment: In `DataTemplate`, the parameters of the function in `x:Bind` can only be members of the class pointed to by `DataType`, that is, the method in `local:Item`, so you can't bind to the current item. It seems that you want to modify the text, you can refer to [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) to achieve similar function.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT That's unfortunate. My current workaround is to provide a `Self` property on `Item` that simply returns itself, allowing me to use `FmtItem(Self)` at the expense of a transient ref count bump. Not great, but not the end of the world either. I'd looked into `IValueConverter` previously, and that can be made to work. I decided against using it for several reasons, most notably because that would mean giving up on compile-time `x:Bind` checking.